# Create a function which take in input a value and its name separated by =

Tags: r, function, arguments

How can I construct a function which can deal with an argument which is made of a name and a value separated by a `=` sign?

For example:

```
foo = myFun(HELLO = 3)
bar = myFun(Tintin = 5)
```

and it constructs:

```
foo = 3
names(foo) = "HELLO"
bar = 3
names(bar) = "Tintin"
```

Of course, I could give the two argument separated by a comma but it's not the point of my question!

There are many functions in R that works like this.

```
data.frame(a=1:5, babar=2:6)
cbind(jf=1:3, ij=4:6)
```

(I guess the solution might have to do with the use of `…` in the function argument).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very minimal example:

```
foo <- function(...){
    list(...)
}
```

In use:

```
> foo(x = 4)
$x
[1] 4

> foo(x = 4,y = 5)
$x
[1] 4

$y
[1] 5
```

And that can always be `unlist`ed if you want a vector.

Note that this technique can easily and quickly be divined by simply scanning through the code of the two example functions you cited. Both `data.frame` and `cbind` gather the arguments in `...` via `x <- list(...)` early in their source code.